# How can I export Exact material name with FBX?

Tags: export

I exported from blender to a fbx file and I use a converter that convert to a custom format for game engine, but fbx export name of material with image name like this

```
Material: "Material::GroundMat__ground_jpg", "" {
        Version: 102
        ShadingModel: "lambert"
        MultiLayer: 0
```

but I want just Material name like "GroundMat", is there any possibility that i can export just material name?